# Getting started with Less CSS framework

Tags: css, css-frameworks

I'm trying to create a couple of static HTML pages for demo purpose. I decided [Less 4 CSS framework](http://lessframework.com/)

For now, I have two pages to demo:

1. Login page: contains a header and a login form at the center of the page.
2. Usual suspect page: header, footer, main content.

I don't know how to partition Less grid to fit my requirements. How to divide and partition Less 4 grid?

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning it too. As far as I know, LESS framework and its successor http://framelessgrid.com/ require you to manually write the CSS and HTML first.  Then you use Joni Korpi's LESS to adapt it for mobile devices.  <strike>Will update you as I progress myself.</strike>

Check out this answer. Basically, every element is set to certain column widths using `.col1, .col2`, etc

[How to effectively use the Frameless grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049335/how-to-effectively-use-the-frameless-grid)

And I asked this question to understand LESS css.

[How to read this LESS css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889191/how-to-read-this-less-css)